# Create dialog box above other android apps when using intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create dialog box such that when other apps call it using intent, so only dialog box will appear over that respective apps.

I know how to use Internet filters and get data from them just want to create dialog box over it. Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbzrl.png

In this screenshot the dialog box is of android download manager and below that is chrome.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [**DialogFragment**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) inside your `Activity`? It will behave just like a normal android dialog, but it's lifecycle will be different, just like in normal `Fragment` - so you'll be able to save state and so on.

For example, if your `MyDialogFragment` extends `DialogFragment`, then in your `MyActivity` you would call:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction tx = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment previous = manager.findFragmentByTag("MyDialogFragmentTAG");
    if (previous == null){
        MyDialogFragment frg = new MyDialogFragment();
        frg.show(tx, "MyDialogFragmentTAG");
        //no need to commit transaction, DialogFragment takes care of it
    }
    //....
}
```